# I cannot embed Font Awesome Icons in my page

Tags: html, font-awesome

I link Font Awesome to my page using the Bootstrap CDN.

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@5.15.4/css/fontawesome.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-jLKHWM3JRmfMU0A5x5AkjWkw/EYfGUAGagvnfryNV3F9VqM98XiIH7VBGVoxVSc7" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

However when I try to use the classes indicated at the Font Awesome website all I get is a small square where the icon was supposed to be.

Any suggestions on how to fix that?

The html code is shown below.

```
<section id="services">

        <div class="container-fluid services-container">

            <div class="row">
                <i class="fa-light fa-fire-extinguisher"></i>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                    <h3 class="text-styling">Συντήρηση Πυροσβεστήρων</h3>
                    <p class="text-styling">Ut facere voluptatem ea neque tempora sed praesentium magni nam omnis dolor.
                        In sint consectetur
                        sit
                        consectetur molestias qui quidem cumque qui eius sint? Et labore dignissimos eum deleniti
                        consequatur
                        sed laborum dolore et adipisci nulla.
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                    <h3 class="text-styling">Μελέτες Πυρασφάλειας</h3>
                    <p class="text-styling">Ut facere voluptatem ea neque tempora sed praesentium magni nam omnis dolor.
                        In sint consectetur
                        sit
                        consectetur molestias qui quidem cumque qui eius sint? Et labore dignissimos eum deleniti
                        consequatur
                        sed laborum dolore et adipisci nulla.
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                    <h3 class="text-styling">Συστήματα Πυρανίχνευσης</h3>
                    <p class="text-styling">Ut facere voluptatem ea neque tempora sed praesentium magni nam omnis dolor.
                        In sint consectetur
                        sit
                        consectetur molestias qui quidem cumque qui eius sint? Et labore dignissimos eum deleniti
                        consequatur
                        sed laborum dolore et adipisci nulla.
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                    <h3 class="text-styling">Πιστοποίηση</h3>
                    <p class="text-styling">Ut facere voluptatem ea neque tempora sed praesentium magni nam omnis dolor.
                        In sint consectetur
                        sit
                        consectetur molestias qui quidem cumque qui eius sint? Et labore dignissimos eum deleniti
                        consequatur
                        sed laborum dolore et adipisci nulla.
                    </p>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </section>
```

Comment: Try `<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@5.15.4/css/fontawesome.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-jLKHWM3JRmfMU0A5x5AkjWkw/EYfGUAGagvnfryNV3F9VqM98XiIH7VBGVoxVSc7" crossorigin="anonymous">`

Comment: @Grim nope doesn't work either. Why would changing https to http have any impact though?

Comment: @kosgian90 Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be tested by others.

Comment: First, you may use incorrect version of Font Awesome icon class name. Second, you may use PRO icon while you don't have PRO account. Third, please attach reproducible code. What icon name or what CSS classes do you use?

Comment: @vee I edited the post so that it shows which class I use.

Comment: It's really as I said. You are using incorrect class version. You use CSS for version 5 but [`fa-light`](https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/setup/upgrade/whats-changed#full-style-names) is only for V.6. And the [light icon](https://fontawesome.com/v5/icons/fire-extinguisher?s=light) is only for PRO whether it is in V.5 or [V.6](https://fontawesome.com/v6/icons/fire-extinguisher?s=light). Please carefully use icon class name matched the CSS version you use and avoid PRO if you don't have accessible to it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Font Awesome, or to get your script via this link : https://fontawesome.com/start .
Enter your email to get started with a free Kit!
Go to confirm your email and they will give you the script

Comment: I thought that this step could be circumvented if I used the Bootstrap CDN for Font Awesome.

Comment: I haven't tried it before but you try it and if it doesn't work try my suggestion it's very simple